# Retain State of dynamically created checkbox using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox, retain

I have a couple of checkboxes placed inside a dynamically created list using JQuery. The list refreshes after 10 seconds. How do I retain the status of the checkboxes inside the list after list refresh.
Here's my HTML markup :

```
enter code here

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
  <head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js">
  </head>
<body>
   <ul>
      <li><label for='machineBlock'> Blocked </label>
          <input type='checkbox' name='Checkbox1' id='machineBlock' value='1'>
     </li>
     <li><label for='machineStarve'> Starved </label>
         <input type='checkbox' name='Checkbox2' id='machineStarve' value='2'>
     </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my JS Code

```
$(":checkbox").on("click", function () {
   var isChecked = $(":checkbox").is(":checked");
   if(isChecked == true) {
      var checkboxValues = {};
      $(":checkbox").each(function(){
      checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
      localStorage.setItem('checkboxValues' , checkboxValues);
  });
  $(":listid").listview('refresh');
  var isData = localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues');
  if(!data){
   $(":checkbox").each(function () {
     $(this).prop('checked', true);
  }
```

Any Help would be appreciated. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: `$(this).prop("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");`.

Comment: Shouldn't `if (!data)` be `if (!isData)` ?